# Ruby refactoring

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I am making a simple rails site that will store some date and perform basic conditional checks. I wrote a few methods below and was told I could make them more efficient. I have been scratching my head and I'm not sure how to do this. Should I make entry.find global? or is there a more obvious solution? Thanks in advance

```
 def name
     @fname = params[:fst_name]
     @lname = params[:lst_name]
     @entry = Entry.create({:first_name => @fname, :last_name =>  @lname})
  end

  def attribs
     @person = Entry.find(:last)
     @fname = @person.first_name
     @lname = @person.last_name
     @person.update_attributes({:address => params[:st_name], 
         :salary => params[:salary], :loan => params[:loan], 
         :loan_reason => params[:reason]})
     if !@person.address.nil? then render "show" end
  end

 def show
     @person = Entry.find(:last)
 end

  def modify
     @person = Entry.find(:last)
     @fname = @person.first_name
     @lname = @person.last_name
     @entry = Entry.create({:first_name => @fname, :last_name =>  @lname,  
                            :salary => params[:salary], :loan => params[:loan]})
  end

 def borrow
     @person = Entry.find(:last)
     if !@person.salary.nil? then
       if (@person.salary *  3) < @person.loan
            then @message = "You have asked for too much"
       else  @message = "No problem" 
       end
    else @message = "empty record?"
    end
 end


end
```

Comment: This sort of question probably should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a before_filter for the cases where you are repeatedly using `@person = Entry.find(:last)`
- Don't make every variable an instance variable: for `name`: you don't need to acces `@fname` in the view, you can do `@entry.first_name` if you need to.
- Don't use inline `if then`, use `do_something if condition`. Also remove the `then` from your other `if`s too.
- You may want to move the `Event` creation into the model. Something like `self.create_from_person_and_modify_params`
- Use `Event.last` instead of `Event.find(:last)`
- Use `if @person.salary` instead of `if !@person.salary.nil?`
- Move the `if (@person.salary *  3) < @person.loan` condition into the model. Something like `asks_for_reasonable_raise?`